# jquery detect coordinate of top of page after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 'back button' that I would like to stick to the header until you scroll past a certain point (so I have it absolutely positioned but would like it positioned 'fixed' when you scroll past the header).

Kinda like the 'GAMEHQ' section does here: http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/preview?gameId=311027124

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function which gives you information about where you are in the page is [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). With it you can detect if you're past a certain point, and then modify the CSS of an item to make it `position: fixed`, for example.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 120) {
            $('#topThing').css('position', 'fixed');
        } else {
            $('#topThing').css('position', 'relative');
        }
    });
});
```

[And here's a JSFiddle showing how it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/gHPsE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This example uses jQuery but could be altered fairly easily. This function should be close to what you want. The `100` is the number of pixels down the page you'd want to change the class of your #nav. In your CSS you'd then want to make sure you had a `#nav.scrolling` declaration to handle the change to `position: fixed`.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#nav").addClass("scrolling");
  }
});
```